# How to move a joint in a rig using Parenting to anything? See Image

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

Please help. This is to cleanup fk legs
[image: look at the image. How to move a joint only. Using Parenting?]

Comment: if you want to make the cube the parent then give your bone a Child Of constraint

Comment: Then the whole Joints group is moving. I want only one Joint to move. Please help

Comment: because the top bone is child of your middle bone. You should try to explain what is your final goal, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Moonboots. Yes, I want to move only child joint. Mostly in other softwares like Maya( Not comparing), it is possible. But I'm searching for a solution in Blender. This I want to do to clean up MOCAP fk legs. To make feet stay on the ground.

Comment: maybe show what you want more clearly with 2 or 3 pictures, I think it will help to understand. For example I'm not sure how you want the top bone to act, will it stretch when the middle bone will move?